# yii commands not working inside the yii2 application

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to run yii commands inside my yii2 application and it's not working.

```
php yii
```

This should normally return all the commands that is available. But it's not returning anything and is just going to the next line.

The application is already running in the server, so I don't think this is because of initialisation problems.

> Contents of the yii file

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
* Yii console bootstrap file.
*/

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/bootstrap.php';

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php',
require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php',
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php',
require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php'
);

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

[image]

> Root folder contents

[image]

Comment: Can you pls show the folder and file list of your root app folder

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot @ZiyaVakhobov

Comment: Please turn on your error reporting and see if there is any errors

Comment: There is no error! ;( @Justinas

Comment: Can you show contents of `yii` file?

Comment: Updated it in the question @Justinas

Comment: Does `./yii help` shows something? Or `./yii && date`?

Comment: Nope. Same result as `php yii` @rob006

Comment: It probably means some fatal error. You need to enable error reporting and displaying errors to see what is happening. Or search for some `exit` or `die` calls which may terminate script.

Comment: Can we say that this be a fatal error if the app is working fine? @rob006

Comment: if you type in `./yii` from the application root, and hit enter what does it print on the console ?

Comment: It doesn't print anything! @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: that is strange does typing `php init` displays something or its also behaves the same?

Comment: and your web application is running correctly apart from this behavior on the terminal?

Comment: Yes the application is working perfectly!

Comment: `php init` is going into to initialization tool window like it's supposed to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191524/discussion-between-bohemianjock-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Answer (score 1):

if you have the composer installed you must execute the command

`composer install`

in the root folder of your project